# Get Thing Shadow with AWS-SDK v3 using "client-iot-data-plane"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot, aws-sdk-nodejs

I need to get the shadow of a thing in a lambda. Since we upgraded from V2 to V3 SDK we are having problems using the "IoT Data Plane Client" to interact with shadow, when we try to send a "GetThingShadowCommand" it returns a 403 ForbiddenException.

```
import {
    GetThingShadowCommand, 
    GetThingShadowCommandInput, 
    IoTDataPlaneClient 
    } from "@aws-sdk/client-iot-data-plane";

[...]


public async getData(dispenserId: string): Promise<object> {
                try {
                    const dispenser = await Dispenser.findById(dispenserId)
                    const iotDataPlaneClient = new IoTDataPlaneClient({
                        region: process.env.DEPLOYMENT_REGION
                    });
                    const input: GetThingShadowCommandInput = { // GetThingShadowRequest
                        thingName: dispenser.serial, // required
                        shadowName: "Device_Shadow",
                    };
                    const command = new GetThingShadowCommand(input);
                    const response = await iotDataPlaneClient.send(command);
                    const shadow: object = JSON.parse(response.payload.toString())
                    return response.payload
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log('!!!ERROR CAUGHT IN GET DATA SERVICE!!!')
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2))
                    return err
                }
            }
```

in the serverless file we allowed the actions for iot

```
[...]
{
                    Effect: "Allow",
                    Action: [
                        "iot:Publish",
                        "iot:GetThingShadow",
                        "iot:ListNamedShadowsForThing",
                        "iot:UpdateThingShadow",
                        "iot:DeleteThingShadow",

                    ],
                    Resource: ["*"]
                }
[...]
```

this is the full error printed:

```
{
    "name": "ForbiddenException",
    "$fault": "client",
    "$metadata": {
        "httpStatusCode": 403,
        "requestId": "ec8d4b5d-1ae5-77ce-7166-9cbfeb1df1fa",
        "attempts": 1,
        "totalRetryDelay": 0
    },
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "traceId": "ec8d4b5d-1ae5-77ce-7166-9cbfeb1df1fa"
}
```

i expect to receive the shadow as

```
{
  "state": {
    "desired": {
        "prop1":"value1",
        "prop2":"value2"
    },
    "reported": {
        "prop1":"value1",
        "prop2":"value2"

    }
  }
}
```

or something similar to this

Comment: Would iot:* solve your problem? Just trying to make sure it is a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when not all permissions required for interacting with `iot` were defined in `serverless.yml` .

I suggest to have something like this:

```
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - "iot:Get*"
        - "iot:List*"
        - "iot:Describe*"
        - "iot:Subscribe"
        - "iot:Connect"
        - "iot:Publish"
        - "iot:Update*"
      Resource: "*"
```